# A way to keep the "user bar" on the top of the site stuck there ~ StickyBar

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Screenshot]

### About

Since people keep asking for a way to stick the userbar at the top of the screen, I'm working on a userscript to do so. Because of the way each site is fashioned and themed, various elements are in different places. So there are some parts that don't work "quite right" such as notifications (aka the supermulticollider), but otherwise it's pretty usable for the basic parts.

#### License

License? Bah. It's a userscript. I'm gonna go with everything else on this site: CC-BY-SA

#### Download

Feel free to download the userscript here: (for now, stay tuned to this space for updates)

http://josh.gitlin.name/drachenstern/stickyuserbar.user.js

#### Platform

Any browser that supports userscripts. That's quite a few of them, but nothing IE8 or lower.

### Contact

I [drachenstern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109749/drachenstern) am the only dev on this project right now.

### Code

It's all in javascript/jQuery. I'll get it onto a repo somewhere once I'm a little happier with it, but for now, it's just being developed by me. If you want to download it and play with it, feel free to. Keep in mind I'm still trying to tune it and get it working *just so*

Comment: PS: EXPECT UPDATES IN THE NEAR FUTURE (after that I have no idea :p )

Comment: It covers up the notifications :(

Comment: @jleedev i know I have some updates I need to finish and reupload :/ ... I thought I would have had time to update it before now ... [[ damn you work and family life and a recent move demanding unboxing and such ... damn you!!! ]]

Comment: @drachenstern Why does it change the text align of the text inside `hot questions`, `all sites` and `inbox` on StackOverflow site? The text is centered and should be aligned to left

Comment: @oscar cos I broke something trivial and haven't had time to properly update the userscript.

Comment: @drachenstern Ok. Will wait until you fix it then. Great script by the way :)

Comment: @drachenstern it still need some fixes, like for example, when a notification bar appears at the top (when you earn a new badge, etc) it overlaps, but I added a hack to fix the `center` align in the inbox

Comment: @Oscar, I started working on that part, and trying to integrate it across all the sites, and ... it's a bit harder than it seems. You're more than welcome to email me at this nick at gmail and I'll send you what I have if you would like to contribute and help ;) ~ I'll even let you take it over if you care ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to properly see the scroll bar when you scroll down, there needs to be a `background-color`. There isn't currently one set for the toolbar, so as a result, when you scroll down, you can't really see the words. So under `#custom-header`, you need to add `background-color:#E9E9E9`. That is the color that SE has picked for the toolbar. The problem with this is that Stack Apps also has the background color for the page as `E9E9E9`. So I added a small border on the bottom. I used `'border-bottom': '1px solid #d0d0d0'`. If you want it darker, [here](http://0to255.com/e9e9e9) is a tool that will help you do that. Consider adding this into the userscript.