# Stackoverflow.com Enhancer (sticky top bars)

Tags: script, navigation

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image]

### About

Stackoverflow.com Enhancer was created this a while ago, to save me scrolling up and down Stack Overflow, by making the top bars stick to the top of the window as shown above.
Then I neatened it up a bit by shrinking the logo to only have the text (don't worry, the logo returns if you scroll to the top) and put it on userscripts.org and now here.

Currently, it only works 100% on any page on Stack Overflow. It is enabled for Super User, but the logo is a bit out of whack, I'll fix that sometime soon.

If the window is less wide than the bar, then the bar will scroll horizontally as you do.

The plan is also to make the questions dynamically wider if I can, to make use of some of the whitespace on wider monitors.

Also see [drachenstern's script](https://stackapps.com/questions/2043). If both are installed, it actually looks better, when scrolling back up, so I suggest you install it as well.

#### License

Free. If you want to modify it, just drop a comment here; I'll say yes, I just want to see what you do to it :)

#### Download

Direct Link: [userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/91338.user.js](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/91338.user.js)

"Homepage": [userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/91338](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/91338)

#### Platform

Works on Chrome (certainly on v11), and I am highly certain it will work on any browser that supports Greasemonkey-type scripts (for example, Firefox)

#### Contact

The best way to contact me is here, in a comment or answer.

#### Code

Coded in JavaScript, which is available in [userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/91338](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/91338) (just don't look at the revision history ;) )

Comment: So I thanks for the cross upvote ;) I do have some work to do on mine still, and if I can ever get home at a decent hour I will ;) ~ Care to collaborate and make it one script? I was thinking about going all github.

Comment: Nice, but it overlaps notifications. Could you move them under the sticky bar?

Comment: @Nyuszika7H When did you install it/ what version do you have? I fixed this in 1.4 a few days ago.

Comment: @drachenstern, sure I'm just getting used to github but I'm not sure how it work with 2 people so if you want to set it up that'd be great!

Comment: @Jonathan I installed it yesterday. Chrome 11.0.672.2 dev. **Update**: I've just realized that I installed the other script, not this one…

Comment: @Nyuszika7H If you install both it should work the best

Comment: Also note that I've not pushed my latest updates. I've been working with some of the SOIS-devs and MSO-chatters to figure some of the hitches out.

Comment: Indeed this feature should be part of StackOverflow. Why we need an "enhancer"?

Answer (score 3):

These links seem to be dead. So here's my quick fix. All you need is something like [CJS Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/ddbjnfjiigjmcpcpkmhogomapikjbjdk?hl=en) (there are different ones for FF and Saf too!)

Then just inject code:

```
;;(function($) {
    function z() {
        var a = $(window).scrollTop(),
            b = $(".topbar").height();
        a > b ? ($(".topbar").css({ position: "fixed", top: 0, "z-index": 999 }), $("body > .container").css({ "margin-top": b })) 
            : ($(".topbar").css({ position: "", top: "", "z-index": "" }), $("body > .container").css({ "margin-top": "" }))
    }
    if (document.readyState == "complete") z();
    else $(window).on('load', z);
    $(window).on("scroll", function(a) {
        this.tmr && clearTimeout(this.tmr);
        this.tmr = setTimeout(z, 10)
    });
})(jQuery)
```

---

> Or I made [**THIS**](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/SETopBar)

Answer (score 0):

My **[Better Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/6926/stack-exchange-improvements-sticky-top-bar-editor-improvements-and-more)** script supports this feature, and it works on all the stack exchange sites :)

[image: alt]

The script also gives you a better editor, and some other improvements if you want them!