# Stack Exchange Improvements - Sticky top bar, new text editor, and more

Tags: app, chrome-extensions, editing, posts

#### About

**[This chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-stack-exchange/ohgloaohphplfbdcbkoobcmbjopjbhnl) replaces the text editor with a much better one that supports markdown, indentation, code formatting, and more!** Also provides options for making the top bar sticky, and hiding the list of sites in the footer.

*Psst, I'm writing this with the new editor!*

**Main features (customizable in settings)**

- editor

  - full markdown support
  - indentation
  - code blocks
  - automatic lists (with nested indentation)
  - block quotes
  - "sticky" toolbar
  - side-by-side edit and preview
  - much more
- cleaner Stack Exchange UI

  - Sticky header bar
  - removes the site list in the footer
  - dims the "How To Format" sidebar

#### Screenshots

[image: screenshot 3]

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: alt]

[image: alt]

#### Download / Install

[Install from the Chrome Extension Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-stack-exchange/ohgloaohphplfbdcbkoobcmbjopjbhnl/related)

#### Code

GitHub repo: https://github.com/tituswoo/better-stack-exchange

#### Contact

Created by [Titus Woo](http://tituswoo.com).

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Shouldn't the main tag of this question be `app` instead of `script`?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​And by the way, the **Insert Snippet** button doesn't work, also shouldn't the top bar be hidden when it's Fullscreen mode? http://i.stack.imgur.com/mccIb.png

Comment: @KevinGuan you're totally right! Just changed the tag to `app` instead. 
Also thanks for the catch! I'll fix that tonight. :)

Comment: Fixed in `v0.0.5`:
- sticky top bar hidden in fullscreen mode and for snippet previewing

- **insert snippet** button will only appear on stackoverflow (other SE sites don't support snippets AFAIK)

Thanks again for reporting those bugs @KevinGuan!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41486/discussion-between-kevin-guan-and-titus).

Comment: I feel the editor should be a separate extension from the UI changes you make. I don't want a sticky nav bar, thanks, and I'm not sure why the footer needed updating. I'd love to try just the editor though.

Comment: (And yes, these are separate options you can disable, it just feels the extension has been overloaded).

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
Using the 'code' button inserts a tripple-backtick block:

````
```
...
```
````

which is a *GitHub extension*, not supported on Stack Exchange sites. Please change this to use indentation instead.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
Preview options are confusing and partly broken.

- Neither the side-by-side preview nor the inline preview can render Stack Exchange specific markup. For example, the `[tag:bug]` markup I used in this post is not rendered as a tag, it's just the literal text.
- I can only have a live preview in full-screen mode, the regular Stack Overflow preview is not shown below the post.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
I can't edit a post in-line. Already posted answers can't be edited *in the page*; a separate page is opened instead, removing all the context.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
Because a separate edit control is used, and text is moved from that control over to the (hidden) 'real' text editor control when you hit 'post', the anti-bot measures kick in and you are always asked to verify that you are human with the Google Captcha.

Perhaps if you continually update the 'real' post box as you edit, the anti-bot measure doesn't have to kick in (as you then show that you have been editing the post for more than just a fraction of a second).